# Why does my Material UI Divider not show up in a Material UI Container or Paper?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, divider

Good morning,

I am in love with Material UI, there is so much one can do. However, after using it extensively, I have noticed that a Material UI Divider does not show up when it is the child of a Container or Paper component. I can't find anything as to why this is the case, so it is probably my implementation. Could someone check it out and see why it isn't appearing?

Everything is imported, the Popover works fine.

Thank you!

```js
navBarPopover: {
    display: "flex",
    flexDirection: "column",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
}

<Popover 
    id={id}
    open={open}
    anchorEl={anchorEl}
    onClose={handleClose}
    anchorOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
    }}
    transformOrigin={{
        vertical: "top",
        horizontal: "right",
    }}
>
  <Container className={clsx(classes.navBarPopover)}>
      <Button className={clsx(classes.loginButton)} component={Link} to="/user_auth" onClick={() => handleClose()}>
          Login
      </Button>
      <Divider />
      <Button className={clsx(classes.loginButton)} component={Link} to="/faqs" onClick={() => handleClose()}>
          FAQs
      </Button>
  </Container>
</Popover>
```

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I agree, Material-UI is really awesome.
In this issue, you're giving `display:'flex'` to the parent container. By giving `flex`, the child elements take the minimum possible width as `flex-shrink` is there on child elements by default.
So, here the `Divider` is there but its width is 0. Provide width to 100%.

```
<Divider style={{width:'100%'}} />
```

Check the demo here:- https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-euler-2ycv4

##### Edit: Feb 2023

as @Lesik2008 has mentioned in [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568238/why-does-my-mui-divider-not-show-up-in-a-mui-container-or-paper/65572655#comment128255155_65572655), you can use `flexItem` prop as well to indicate that this is flex item and it'll calculate the height accordingly. Pass `flexItem` as `true`.
much smaller and cleaner.

```
<Divider flexItem />
```

Comment: Maybe it didn't exist when this was posted, but I think nowadays it's cleaner to use [the `flexItem` prop of Divider](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/divider/#props), which achieves the same thing without manual style overwrites.

Comment: yes @Lesik2008, we can use that. But that prop works only for vertical dividers.  
You can [here](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/divider/#props:~:text=If,height%20when%20used)

Comment: @Rajiv Docs said that is for vertical, but it works for horizontal dividers too

Comment: Does not work for me.