# Material Divider UI: Error is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DividerProps'

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using Material UI 4 for React, and receiving error below. How do I fix? It actually works in modifying CSS, and I got similar code from here  [Why does my MUI Divider not show up in a MUI Container or Paper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65568238/why-does-my-mui-divider-not-show-up-in-a-mui-container-or-paper) .

**Code:**

```
  <Divider style={{ padding: '1px' }} />
```

**Error:**

```
(property) style: {
    padding: string;
}
Type '{ style: { padding: string; }; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DividerProps'.
  Property 'style' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & DividerProps'.ts(2322)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MUI encourages the usage of `sx` prop and prefers it over `style` attribute.

```
  <Divider sx={{ padding: "1px" }} />
```

https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/

With `sx` you can shorten your styling object even further by using `p` instead of `padding`:

```
  <Divider sx={{ p: "1px" }} />
```